# The proper use of jsoup

Tags: append, jsoup, attr

I recently began to study how to use jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(responseString); 
 Elements pngs = doc.select ("div.kk2");
```

To using jsoup made ​​a web page to put pictures of  example I

```
<div class="kk2" id="12" style="border:2px solid #FFFF00; top:-1px; left:-203px; height:151px; width:200px"> <img src = "http:// kk.org / t / ea / ff.jpg "alt =" text "style =" fff "/> </ div>
```

After screening of the example

```
   for(Element png : pngs){
              sff2.append(png.attr("abs:href")).append("  ").append(png.text()).append("\n");
          }
```

To obtain this value

```
init ~ kk.org ~ t / ea / ff.jpg ~ text
```

If I simply just want to get this value

```
http://kk.org/t/ea/ff.jpg
```

How can I do it??
I try to use

```
sff2.append (png.attr ("alt")). append (""). append (png.text ()). append ("\ n");
```

But without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to get the address of the image?
If so, this should do it.

```
Elements div = doc.select("div[class=kk2]");
Elements pngs = div.select("img");

for (Element png : pngs) {
        String src = png.attr("abs:src");
        src = src.replace(" ", ""); // Remove spaces
        System.out.println(src);
}
```